# How to clear previous content from a table cell

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a "clearing" function to my table that calculates totals. So that when person first time presses button that does the calculation, then changes amounts of products and then presses again, the previous answer would be cleared and new added.

I have tried like this:

```
function clear () {
    var table = document.getElementById("pricetable");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].className = "";
        var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (var j = 1; j < cells.length - 1; j++) {
            cells[j].className = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'm calling the function in the beginning of my previous function that calculates the amounts and prices:

```
function calculate () {
    clear ();
    ... 
}
```

But nothing happens. I was thinking that it might have something to do with the fact that I have created the last row and also the last column (which both include the totals) dynamically. The id of the row is lastRow, and the column doesn't have id.

And I don't want to use jquery or add classes, ids etc to the html file. So does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Could it be that you're setting `className` property, and you need to use something else?

Comment: Welcome to SO and nice work on a well presented question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className` just clears styling.

You're looking for `innerHTML`:

```
...
for (var j = 1; j < cells.length - 1; j++) {
    cells[j].innerHTML = "";
}
...
```

---

`className` refers to the CSS class name(s) applied to an element.  Here's what your current code does:

*Before*

```
<td class='foo'>999</td>
```

*After*

```
<td class=''>999</td>
```

---

`innerHTML` pretty much does what it says:

*Before*

```
<td class='foo'>999</td>
```

*After*

```
<td class='foo'></td>
```

---

Also, I just noticed your `for` loop starts at 1.  Hopefully this was intentional ;)

Comment: Thanks! Now it cleares all content away. But I would like the last column and last rows 4th and 5th(which is last) cell to be cleared.. Do you know how I should change the code for doing that?

Comment: You're welcome!  Accessing the `n`th cell is probably something that you'll do in your `for` loop, by starting and ending on the range you want to affect.  Otherwise, you'll have to do it piecemeal by accessing members of the array by their index, i.e. `cells[5].innerHTML = ''` and `cells[cells.length - 1].innerHTML = ''`.

Comment: Yes thank you!  `cells[5].innerHTML = "";` cleares the last column the way I wanted it. But on the 4th column  I would like only the cell from last row to be cleared..  I tried accessing it with `var last = document.getElementByID("lastRow").cells[7];` and then `last.innerHTML = "";` but it's not doing what I wish it to do.

Comment: Well, we're getting outside the scope of the question here (SO community likes 1 topic per question) but you're on the right track - what you're looking for is to access the *rows* array now:  `var lastRow = rows[rows.length - 1]; lastRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[7].innerHTML = ''`.

Comment: Also, if you have a node list of table rows, you can use `rows.cells[7]` in some situations if you set it up right.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are setting the `className` to nothing rather than setting the `innerHTML` to nothing...

Try replacing this:

```
cells[j].className = "";
```

With this:

```
cells[j].innerHTML = "";
```